# Ubuntu Gnome 3.14 GTK+ theme locations

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, themes, gnome, gnome-3

Where are the theme ( css and/or xml ) files stored which contain the default themes of Mutter ( the window manager ) on Gnome 3.14?

i.e.: There is the *Numix* theme, which is installed by default, but I cannot find the files it fetches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this is what you want:

```
/usr/share/themes/
```

comment update:

```
/usr/share/themes/Numix/gtk-3.0/
```

There are 2 files depends on what you use:

**gtk.css**, **gtk-dark.css**

if you want to change the bg color (for example) you have to modify the following row:

```
@define-color bg_color #2d2d2d;
```

Comment: This was useful. However, I can still only find the theme files of the top bar (  window decoration ), and not the global GTK+ theme. Please, specify the path.